# General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint, Laravel 5 & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

In a blank Laravel project, I want to create foreign key constraint between **users** and **questions**, where `users` table will hold build-in Laravel `User`, but `Question` will be a custom model.

After running  `php artisan migrate` the follownign error occurs:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `questions` add constraint `questions_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
  at /home/artur/Exposit/EDU/PHP/lara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|
```

Here is create_users_table migration generated by laravel:

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And here is my migration:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->unsignedInteger('views')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('answers')->default(0);
            $table->integer('votes')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

I've tried to separate questions table creation and altering with foreign key constraint into two migrations, but got the same error.
Note, that non of related answers on stackoverflow were helpful to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Laravel 5.8 Added bigIncrements As Defaults**

So there is mismatch in foreign key field types. You see bigIncrements(id) in User table and unsigned Integer(user_id) in questions table.

**How to fix**

- Either change original migration from bigIncrements() to just
  increments()
- Or in your foreign key column do unsignedBigInteger() instead    of
  unsignedInteger().

Comment: Solved my problem by using unsignedBigInteger type. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In user table `bigIncrements('id')` making primary key which is unsigned.

and its type is big integer

while you setting a foreign key its also should be unsigned.

add `unsigned()` function and change the type from `unsignedInteger` to `bigInteger`

Example:

```
 Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->unsignedInteger('views')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('answers')->default(0);
            $table->integer('votes')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

How I fixed it For Laravel 8:
All the migrations generated in L8 is using just `$table->id();` which is bigInteger. Make sure on your second table which is gonna contain foreignkey, you have `$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');`

First set the correct type:

`posts table`

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->id(); //note by default in laravel 8 this is bigint
 $table->string('title')->nullable();
 $table->timestamps();
});
```

`comments table`

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->id();
 $table->string('description')->nullable();
 //foriegn key set up below
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
 $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

Secondly re-order the migration files (the posts migration should be run first before you can run the comments file as laravel cannot find the id of the post to create the foreign key)

`2021_04_10_043454_create_posts_table` -> 04/10 (earlier date will run first)
`2021_04_14_050712_create_posts_table` -> 04/14 (later date runs after)

lastly,
clear cache first `php artisan cache:clear` then run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Data types of primary and foreign keys must be the same.

Please update `questions` migration to:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->text('body');
    $table->unsignedInteger('views')->default(0);
    $table->unsignedInteger('answers')->default(0);
    $table->integer('votes')->default(0);
    $table->unsignedInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable();
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Do the same for `best_answer_id` too if it is also going to be a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

change in migration source table

```
Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->BigIncrements('id');
```

on

```
Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
```